# How to root my Epic 4G on mac?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s, macos

Hello i am trying to root my samsung epic 4g (galaxy s) with my macbook air. I was going to use superoneclick but i cant find a version for mac, does anybody know how i can easily root my phone using my mac?

Comment: [SuperOneClick](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) supports Mac. You simply need to have [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Start) installed.

Comment: This confuses me, why do you have a Mac... and not an iPhone. I mean, if you were smart enough to choose Android instead of iPhone, why do you even have a Mac?

Comment: Also, the above comment is true, you can use Mono to run SuperOneClick to root your phone easily. WINE won't work.

Comment: See also: [Root Samsung Epic Galaxy 4G (SPH-D700) on FC09 Gingerbread?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27028/16575)

Answer (score 1):

There's an article over there at the XDA Forum, titled [Epic 4G Touch Root on Mac or Linux using Heimdall!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1277000). I'm not sure whether these steps apply to your device (not having the "touch" mentioned) -- but as there was no real answer yet, I thought you might give it a try.

The linked article includes a video tutorial, which you might want to watch first. Described steps are as follows:

1. Put your Epic 4G Touch in Download Mode by holding down Volume Down button and Power button together for about 10 seconds then hit Volume Up button. Connect your phone to your computer via a USB cable.
2. Go download the appropriate binaries for your Mac (OSX) or Linux 32-bit or 64bit at glassechidna.com.au
   Get the file with "Binary" or "Binaries".
   For Mac, you will get a .DMG file you can install and for Linux, you will get a .deb file you can install.
   Install these files and open up a command prompt and type:
   `heimdal`
   You should get a bunch of syntax stuff, if so that's good, you have heimdall installed and working.
3. Go download a rooted kernel, I recommend Zedomax Epic Touch Kernel v3:
   [Download Zedomax Epic Touch Kernel v3](http://downloadandroidrom.com/file/Epic4GTouch/kernel/ZedomaxEpicTouchKernel/SPH-D710_Zedomax_EpicTouchKernel-v3.tar)
   *Note - You can also download any other kernel .tar file of your liking.
4. Browse to the directory you've download the tar file by using command "cd":
   `cd /home/myusername/Downloads`
5. Untar the tar file:
   `tar xvf SPH-D710_Zedomax_EpicTouchKernel-v3.tar`
   Double-check you have a zImage file in the directory by typing:
   `ls -l`
6. Type the following to flash:
   `heimdall flash --kernel zImage`
7. Reboot and you can check that you've rooted your phone by going to *Settings->About phone* and see "ZedomaxEpicTouchKernel" in Kernel version.
   Also you will see a new app called "Superuser" in apps.

Congrats, you've been rooted with a Linux or Mac.

---

Several more methods are described at [How To | Epic 4G Touch Root](http://epic4gtouchroot.com/tag/how-to/), and may be even more up-to-date. So please make sure to check them as well before you start. When done, we (the community) of course appreciate your feedback which method(s) you tried and how you succeeded.